# after delete deployments: deployments/scale.apps "xxx" not found

Tags: kubernetes

I try delete the deployment, and then `event center` says one warning: `FailedGetScale`.

```
deployments/scale.apps "xxxx" not found
```

I have no way to check the problem, nor can I find a similar description. Have any friends ever encountered similar problems, or how to deal with this error?

Thanks!
Gemo

Answer (score 0):

Got it! I forgot to delete the `hpa`, and it's fixed now.

```bash
kubectl get hpa
```

and delete the `kubectl delete hpa <hap-name>`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).